# How do you add a class and style to an HTML.ActionLink which routes to a section

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html.actionlink

I have the following action link which goes to a particular section in a view.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Morn Info", "Solutions", "Home", null, null, "EOB",null, null)
```

How do I add a **style and class** to this `Html.ActionLink` to make it look like a `button`?

I feel like I could add...

```
new { @class = "button btn-flat", @style = "border-radius: 14px;" }
```

but I cannot get it to work like this...

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Early Out Billing", "Solutions", "Home", new { @class = "button btn-flat", @style = "border-radius: 14px;" }, null, "EOB", null, null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

htmlAttributes is the last value in your ActionLink constructor.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Morn Info", 
"Solutions", 
"Home", 
null, 
null, 
"EOB", 
null, 
new { @class = "button btn-flat", @style = "border-radius: 14px;" })
```